# An inequality from Green-Tao "The primes contain arbitrary long arithmetic progressions"

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, additive-combinatorics

I have been reading "The primes contain arbitrary long arithmetic progressions" by Green and Tao (The version on the ArXiv: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404188v6.pdf) going through the details and there is this inequality I am not seeing at the moment. I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain me how to get it.

The inequality is on p27 around (7.7) and (7.8). I think for the purpose of this question we can assume $\nu$ is a positive function defined on $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ and $A$ is some subset of $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ where $N$ is a large prime.
Suppose we have
$$
\mathbb{E}((v-1) \mathbf{1}_A) + 2\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_A)  \geq \eta^{1/2}
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb{E}((v-1) \mathbf{1}_A) = o_{\eta}(1) + O(\eta).
$$
Then how do we deduce from these that
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}((v-1) \mathbf{1}_A) }{\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_A) } = o_{\eta}(1) + O(\eta^{1/2}).
$$
I would greatly appreciate any comments/answers! Thank you very much!

PS here $\mathbb{E}(f) = (1/N)\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}} f(x)$.

PPS $\eta$ is a small positive number here.

Comment: In your PS, you probably mean to sum over $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$, not $\mathbb Z/Z\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Is $\eta$ large or small?

Comment: @FedorPetrov $\eta$ is a small positive number here. I guess I should add that as well. thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have the freedom to choose $\eta$ sufficiently small and $N$ sufficiently big. So you can certainly assume that $\mathbb{E}((v-1)1_A) = O(\eta)$ (by taking $N$ sufficiently large) with big O constant so small that when plugged into the first inequality, $\mathbb{E}(1_A) \ge 0.01 \eta^{1/2}$, by taking $\eta$ sufficiently small so that $\eta^{1/2}$ dominates. Then the result follows.

Comment: @JohnnyT. what does $o_\eta(1)$ mean?

Comment: @Turbo $o_{\eta}(1)$ means this value goes to $0$ as $N$ gets large and the rate may depend on the value of $\eta$. (at least that's my understanding...)